# Issues with using filesystem on Cmake Ubuntu terminal

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, c++17

I've been searching everywhere for the solution to this issue to no avail. I'm running a DigitalOcean droplet running ubuntu. I only have access to the terminal. I'm taking code that builds perfectly fine on windows and moving it to the VM. When I use the 'cmake ..' command it works fine, then on 'make' I'm given 'Undefined reference to {Insert your choice of filesystem function here}.

It seems similar to this issue:
[Problem adding std::filesystem to CMake Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290254/problem-adding-stdfilesystem-to-cmake-project)
However, the author wrote that the solution was to update g++ and gcc to 8.2. This did not solve my issue so here I am.

I have the flag set to use c++17 and to stop build if it is not using it for whatever reason and I believe that is where it fails as it shows me this:

```
-- ENABLE_CPP11        = ON       <--------
-- BUILD_EXAMPLES      = OFF
-- BUILD_TESTS         = OFF
...
```

Among other info that doesn't seem relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would appear that you are not linking correctly to `filesystem`. Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545562/what-is-the-correct-way-to-link-c17-filesystem-with-cmake) help?

Comment: @thomas_f it runs fine on windows. It is only when I run it on the VM that it fails. This indicates to me that I'm missing c++17.