# Is there an elegant way to allow either c++ <experimental/filesystem> or <filesystem> in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I maintain a [project](https://github.com/beroset/autoproject) written mostly in C++ that uses the `<filesystem>` feature of C++17.  This code is intended to be run on Linux machines with either clang or gcc as the compiler.  Recently, I learned that the current Ubuntu Long-Term Support (LTS) version uses gcc version 7.5 which is much older than the version 10.2 that I am using.  The result is that on that version of gcc under Ubuntu LTS, it was still an experimental feature and so was in `<experimental/filesystem>`.  To accomodate this, in each of the relevant source code files I have this:

```c++
#if HAS_FILESYSTEM
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#else
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
#endif
```

Inspired by this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54290906/3191481
the `CMakeFiles.txt` file contains this.

```cmake
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    try_compile(HAS_FILESYSTEM "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/temp" 
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compilertests/has_filesystem.cpp" 
        CMAKE_FLAGS -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
        LINK_LIBRARIES stdc++fs)
    if (NOT HAS_FILESYSTEM)
        try_compile(HAS_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/temp" 
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compilertests/has_experimental_filesystem.cpp" 
            CMAKE_FLAGS -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            LINK_LIBRARIES stdc++fs)
    endif()
else()
    try_compile(HAS_FILESYSTEM "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/temp" 
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compilertests/has_filesystem.cpp")
    if (NOT HAS_FILESYSTEM)
        try_compile(HAS_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/temp" 
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compilertests/has_experimental_filesystem.cpp")
    endif()
endif()

if(HAS_FILESYSTEM)
    message(STATUS "Compiler has filesystem support")
    set(HAS_FILESYSTEM 1)
else()
    if(HAS_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM)
        message(STATUS "Compiler has experimental filesystem support")
        set(HAS_FILESYSTEM 0)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Compiler is missing filesystem capabilities")
    endif(HAS_EXPERIMENTAL_FILESYSTEM)
endif(HAS_FILESYSTEM)
```

The two files used by the `try_compile` lines above are these:

### has_filesystem.cpp

```c++
#include <filesystem>
int main() {
    std::filesystem::path mypath{"../"};
}
```

### has_experimental_filesystem.cpp

```c++
#include <experimental/filesystem>
int main() {
    std::experimental::filesystem::path mypath{"../"};
}
```

I also use a config file which is populated by CMake and contains this line:

```
#define HAS_FILESYSTEM @HAS_FILESYSTEM@
```

### My questions

1. This seems rather ungainly.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?
2. Because I use the `HAS_FILESYSTEM` value in a `config.h.in` file, I convert it to a number.   Here again, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Be warned that there are [significant differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40899267/8586227) in **using** the two versions as well.  Current compilers still support the TS version, so maybe you want to use just it for now if you have to support it anyway?

Comment: @DavisHerring: It's a good point.  My testing has revealed no circumstance in which the two differ in the subset I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

> To accomodate this, in each of the relevant source code files I have this:
>
> ```cpp
> #if HAS_FILESYSTEM
> #include <filesystem>
> namespace fs = std::filesystem;
> #else
> #include <experimental/filesystem>
> namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
> #endif
> ```

You could put that single snippet of boilerplate in a custom header named something like `my_filesystem.hpp` and include that where needed instead of the copy-paste of the boilerplate.

Some compilers have a flag that you can use to include a file in every source file, such as [GCC's `-include` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options). If your project only needs to support such compilers, you can then just add this flag to a CMake target using `target_compile_options(<target> PRIVATE "SHELL:-include <path>")`.

You can also inline your `has_filesystem.cpp` and `has_experimental_filesystem.cpp` files into your CMake config files by using [the `check_cxx_source_compiles` function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXSourceCompiles.html), which is just a convenience wrapper around `try_compile`.

As for your second quesiton, you've only shown one usage of your `HAS_FILESYSTEM` macro (`#if HAS_FILESYSTEM`), and I can't see any problem with that.